# How to fix passportjs logout sessions ?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

In Passportjs, in order to logout after login and using google accounts I'm using this:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

After clicking on logout when I click again on *login with google* it directly logged me into the accounta instead of asking for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oAuth implementation in passportjs is intended for exactly what is happening right now, this is not an issue.

Logging into oAuth vendor site like fb, tw, google, linkedin etc requires logging into the vendor site (that also not if you are logged on already in alternate browser tab) and a permission to share login info like email etc for the first time only.

The words "Login with Google" should really be "Connect with Google"

Comment: how can I end the sessions created when I click on logout? .Is there any other method to do so?.

Comment: There are references on internet explaining the intent of oAuth. http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26357-oauth-api-vs-useridpassword/ Please review carefully, there is no such thing: "end session upon logout" within the oAuth pattern. There can be several other ways of solving the issue. I recommend you use the straight user/pass pattern and ignore oAuth. Passportjs can be configured easily for this.